# How to load page metadata and insert them to page?

Tags: 2010, enterprise-wiki

I stand before task, perhaps very easy for programmer, but unfortunatelly not for me like SP admin. Let's imagine, that I have a wiki page in Site pages library and my page has some new metadata column with something similar to status, but with one letter or number inside. How can I insert this number/string visibly to page and allow users to rewrite it? It doesen't matter in which form (in lookup WP, form or so on).

Comment: I basically have the same problem...
In Sharepoint 2010 Foundation my WikiLibrary has an added Metadata field called Category. Does anyone know any reason why it DOES NOT show up as a field below the wiki content area even though I have it as required...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a metadata column to a wiki library, the data can be changed by anyone with Edit rights in the wiki library.  It shows as a field below the wiki content area.  The wiki library can also be put into datasheet view and the new column data can be edited in bulk.